# How can I go back to the previous working directory after changing it?

Tags: python, shell, directory

In Python, how can I get the effect of `cd -` in the shell? That is, after [changing the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684), how can I set it back to what it was before that change?

Comment: Busy, can't give a full response. But what you're looking for is [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and `subprocess.popen`. Pass `'cd -'` to the subprocess

Comment: This question has been answered elsewhere on this site:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python

Comment: No I understand the `chdir`, but can you change it relative to the directory you are currently in? (Move back a directory without specifying full path)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking to change the working directory? The [OS module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) in python has a lot of functions to help with this.

```
import os
os.chdir( path )
```

`path` being `".."` to go up one directory. If you need to check where you are before/after a change of directory you can issue the `getcwd()` command:

```
mycwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("..")
#do stuff in parent directory
os.chdir(mycwd)     # go back where you came from
```

Comment: Quick question, how would I go into a directory that is in the current directory without specifying the full path? @Mike

Comment: @SensulPanda - go into the current directory? By definition you're already in the current directory. :)  but the "short cut" to cwd is "."  `os.chdir(".")`, but again, since you're already in the current directory I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. I mean let's say im in a directory called `/example/`. There is a folder in that directory called `test`. If i wanted to write a file to that directory, you would assume the code would look like `/example/test` for a relative directory, but it forces you to specify the full path.

Comment: @SensulPanda - gottcha, yeah, pretty much what I just suggested, the relative path is: `"./test"` that is equivalent to `/<full_path_before_your_stuff>/example/test` if your current working directory is "example"

Comment: Use ``scriptdir =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`` if you want to make paths relative to the script, else otherwise it'll be relative to your ``pwd`` which is sometimes what you want.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question. The author asks for an equivalent of linux's `cd -` (change directory to the previous one, not the parent one).

Comment: @AlexandruIrimiea - How do you figure this doesn't answer the question? The example I gave is *exactly* the same as `cd -`. I chose to use the parent directory `".."` as the example, but you could put any other directory in there and the example works just the same, just as `cd -` does. As a side note to that.. the check mark general means the author has noted that particular answer as the answer to the question that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print(path)
```

will print the CWD of the file, say C:\Users\Test\Documents\CodeRevamp\Joke

```
path2 = os.path.dirname(path)
print(path2)
```

will print the Parent directory of of the file: C:\Users\Test\Documents\CodeRevamp

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly supported. Instead, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821121) what the current working directory is before the change, and save it in a variable; then it will be possible to change to that directory later.

To streamline the process, consider [using a context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169070) to reset the path automatically after a temporary change. For example:

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def temp_chdir(where):
    old = os.getcwd()
    try:
        os.chdir(where)
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(old)
```

which allows code like

```
with temp_chdir('/some/other/path') as f:
    print(os.listdir('.'))
```

The CWD will be restored after the `with` block, even if an exception is raised.