# Code throws FileNotFoundException only on IDLE but not through CMD

Tags: python, python-idle

Simple 2 line Python code is :

```py
import pandas as pd 

pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
```

The above code runs fine when I go to the location of this folder & run from cmd but the same directory has the IDLE.
When I use IDLE to run the same code it throws FileNotFoundError

Can anyone suggest where I am making mistake.

Comment: Better use an absolute path to the file.

Comment: looks like your working directory is set to a different directory. you might want to look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821121/whats-the-working-directory-when-using-idle

Comment: Don't use relative file paths unless you used `os.chdir` or the like to set the working directory to something you *know* makes the relative path correct.

Comment: If you start IDLE with `python -m idlelib` in the directory containing that data file, rather than with an icon or Start entry, then python will find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Basic mistake.

Right clcik on the idle and goto properties.

> **Goto** --> **Shortcut** --> **Start in : "--------"**

This is your default directory where the python is is trying to search the file. Change this directory to the folder where you want the python to search you file.

I recommend to change this directory since you will work on many scripts which you would not want to be stored in default installation directory. 
Better create a seperate folder and give Kudos.