# Python : Change directory

Tags: python

I am using this code to get into the directory in Python:

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Then, I want to exit this directory to the last directory. What do I have to do? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to specify the previous directory python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462833/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-previous-directory-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can run the code `os.getcwd()` before the given line and store into a variable. and cd into this after.

```py
import os
# ...
originalPath = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path)
# process your task
os.chdir(originalPath)
```

Comment if this helps.

Comment: When I run your code, I received this error:
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'cwd'

Comment: it should be `os.getcwd()`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem , this may help.

```
import os

curr = os.getcwd() # this returns current working directory in which this code              #is.store it in curr variable

os.chdir('../') # this will change working directory to specified path.

os.chdir(curr) #now if you wnat to go back to your directory use this
```