# Python "with os.chdir('/opt/intel/mkl/bin'): AttributeError: __enter__" Error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to go the "/opt/intel/mkl/bin" and list the files and check the presence of some files and come out. I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

````
files = ['mklvars.csh','mklvars.sh']
with os.chdir('/opt/intel/mkl/bin'):
    print('testing')
    if all([os.path.isfile(f)for f in files]):
        print("Installation succesful")
    else:
        print("not succesful")```
````

Comment: Help us help you - share the full traceback

Comment: @Mureinik sure,
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 3, in <module>
    with os.chdir('/opt/intel/mkl/bin'):
AttributeError: __enter__```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the keyword `with ... :` with context-manager and `os.chdir()` just isn't a Context Manager.

You can simply do something like (if you don't need working dir to be restored afterwards)

```
files = ['mklvars.csh','mklvars.sh']
os.chdir('/opt/intel/mkl/bin')
print('testing')
if all([os.path.isfile(f) for f in files]):
    print("Installation succesful")
else:
    print("not succesful")
```

But if you need the current working directory to be restored at the end, there are different options you can use.

One example (with https://github.com/jaraco/path):

```
from path import Path

# Changing the working directory:
files = ['mklvars.csh','mklvars.sh']
with Path('/opt/intel/mkl/bin'):
    print('testing')
    if all([os.path.isfile(f)for f in files]):
        print("Installation succesful")
    else:
        print("not succesful")
```

Other solutions: [checkout this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169070/how-do-i-write-a-decorator-that-restores-the-cwd)

For further reading on context-managers:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html
- https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html