# How to create a relative symlink without changing directory?

Tags: python, symlink

I have directory `factory` under which I have app dir `app_1_2_3_4`. I want to create a symlink under `factory` for `app -> app_1_2_3_4` from `/home/user/` dir without using `os.chdir()`, just like this. Don't want full path in link.

```
user@ubuntu % ls -l factory/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx@  1 user  user   13 Mar 15 04:27 app -> app_1_2_3_4
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 user  user  576 Mar 18 17:09 app_1_2_3_4
```

I tried this in python

```py
import os

app_dir_path = '/home/user/factory' + '/' + 'app'
app_dir_ver_path = '/home/user/factory' + '/../' + 'app' + '_{}_{}_{}_{}'.format(major, minor, bugfix, build)
os.symlink(app_dir_ver_path, app_dir_path)
```

But this one creating symlink with full path

```
user@ubuntu % ls -l factory/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx@  1 user  user   13 Mar 15 04:27 app -> /home/user/factory/app_1_2_3_4
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 user  user  576 Mar 18 17:09 app_1_2_3_4
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169070/how-do-i-write-a-decorator-that-restores-the-cwd

Comment: also, never user '/' or '..', us the os methods / helpers like os.path.relpath, os.path.join os.sep, os.pardir ...

Comment: you forgot `major, minor, bugfix, build = 1, 2, 3, 4`

Answer (score 1):

Simply leave out the directory.

```
$ ls -l factory
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 mar 18 18:06 app_1_2_3_4

$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.symlink('app_1_2_3_4', 'factory/bar')
>>> quit()

$ ls -l factory/bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 11 mar 18 18:10 factory/bar -> app_1_2_3_4
```

By the way, `ln -s` works the exact same way:

```
$ ln -s app_1_2_3_4 factory/foo

$ ls -l factory/foo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 11 mar 18 18:09 factory/foo -> app_1_2_3_4
```

Answer (score 1):

[`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink) takes an argument [`dir_fd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#dir-fd) which is a directory descriptor, from the docs:

> If `dir_fd` is not `None`, it should be a file descriptor referring to a directory, and the path to operate on should be relative; path will then be relative to that directory.

You can acquire a directory descriptor with help of [`os.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open), see below.

(Ideally you also want to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) and [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) when joining paths.)

```py
import os

# Assuming you are getting 'app_dir_ver_path' from somewhere else
# and 'major', 'minor', 'bugfix', 'build' are defined.
# "/home/user/factory/app_1_2_3_4"
app_dir_ver_path = os.path.join(
    /home/user/factory,
    f'app_{major}_{minor}_{bugfix}_{build}'
)

# Get the directory where the symlink is supposed to be created:
# "/home/user/factory"
app_dir_ver_name = os.path.dirname(app_dir_ver_path)

# Get the name of the directory to be linked:
# "app_1_2_3_4"
app_dir_ver_base = os.path.basename(app_dir_ver_path)

# Get the directory desciptor:
dir_fd = os.open(app_dir_ver_name, os.O_RDONLY)

# Full path for the symlink:
# "/home/user/factory/app"
app_dir_path = os.path.join(app_dir_ver_name, 'app')

os.symlink(src=app_dir_ver_base, dst=app_dir_path, dir_fd=dir_fd)
```

Run from anywhere on the system, creates symlink in `/home/user/factory`:

```
ls -l /home/user/factory/
lrwxrwxrwx@  1 user  user   13 Mar 15 04:27 app -> app_1_2_3_4
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 user  user  576 Mar 18 17:09 app_1_2_3_4
```

Comment: `app_dir_ver_name` is `app_dir_name`, no?